# NodeJS Type Error issue

Tags: node.js, typeerror

I have been working on a D&D Character creator app to learn a bit of NodeJS. The following code was working fine until I created a few new unrelated functions in a separate file yesterday (dice.js).

Now when running `node app.js newCharacter` from the command line I get the following `TypeError:`

[image]

Most of the code is still just skeleton functions and WIP, but hopefully the pasted code below provides enough information to point out where I'm going wrong.

app.js

```
const fs = require('fs');
const _ = require ('lodash');
const yargs = require('yargs');

const utils =require('./utils.js');
const dice =require('./dice.js');
const character =require('./Character.js');
const races =require('./races.js');

const argv = yargs.argv;
var command = argv._[0];

if (command === 'newCharacter') {
  console.log('----------------------');
  console.log('Creating new character');
  console.log('----------------------');
  var randomCharacter = character.newCharacter();
  console.log(randomCharacter);
  console.log('----------------------');

} else if (command === 'listCharaters'){
  console.log('listing exsiting charaters');
}else if (command === 'removeCharater'){
  console.log('Removing charater');
}else if (command === 'rollDice'){
  console.log("Roll: ", character.rollDice());
}else if (command === 'testFunc'){
  console.log(utils.getRandSex());
}else{
  console.log('Unrecognised command');
}
```

Character.js

```
const dice =require('./dice.js');
const utils =require('./utils.js');
const app =require('./app.js');
const races =require('./races.js');

const _ = require ('lodash');
const yargs = require('yargs');

const argv = yargs.argv;

var newCharacter = () => {
var Character = {};

  Character["Sex"] = utils.getRandSex();

return Character;
};

module.exports = {
newCharacter
}
```

strangely enough when I call a function from another file (such as Dice.js) to set the value of `Character.sex` the program runs successfully, so I initially thought I must have removed the `getRandSex` function from the `module.exports` in `utils.js`, but as you can see below it's still in there.

utils.js

```
const races =require('./races.js');
const dice =require('./dice.js');
const classes =require('./classes.js');
const character =require('./Character.js');
const _ = require ('lodash');

var listChar = () => {}
var removeChar = () => {}
var getChar = () => {}
var calcBaseHP = () => {}
var calcMovementSpeed = () => {}

var getRandName = (race,sex) => {

  if (race === "Human" && sex === "Male"){
    var firstName = _.sample(races.humanMaleNames);
    var lastName  = _.sample(races.humanLastNames) ;
    return (firstName + " " + lastName);
  }
  else if (race === "Human" && sex === "Female"){
    var firstName = _.sample(races.humanFemaleNames);
    var lastName  = _.sample(races.humanLastNames) ;
    return (firstName + " " + lastName);
  }
  else if (race === "Dwarf" && sex === "Male"){
    var firstName = _.sample(races.dwarfMaleNames);
    var lastName  = _.sample(races.dwarfLastNames);
    return (firstName + " " + lastName);
  }
  else if (race === "Dwarf" && sex === "Female"){
    var firstName = _.sample(races.dwarfFemaleNames);
    var lastName  = _.sample(races.dwarfLastNames);
    return (firstName + " " + lastName);
  }
  else return "race not found" +" "+ race;
}

var getRandRace = () => {
  return _.sample(races.race);
}

var getRandClass = () => {
  return _.sample(classes.classes);
}

var getRandAlignment = () => {
  return _.sample(races.alignment);
}

var getRandSex = () => {
  return _.sample(races.sex);
}


var calcBonus = (stat) => {
  var statMod;
  if(stat === 1){
    statMod = -5;
    return statMod;
  }
  else if(stat >= 2 && stat <= 3){
    statMod = -4;
    return statMod;
  }
  else if(stat >= 4 && stat <= 5){
    statMod = -3;
    return statMod;
  }
  else if(stat >= 6 && stat <= 7){
    statMod = -2;
    return statMod;
  }
  else if(stat >= 8 && stat <= 9){
    statMod = -1;
    return statMod;
  }
  else if (stat >= 10 && stat <=11){
    statMod = 0;
    return statMod;
  }
  else if (stat >= 12 && stat <=13){
    statMod = +1;
    return statMod;
  }
  else if (stat >= 14 && stat <=15){
    statMod = +2;
    return statMod;
  }
  else if (stat >= 16 && stat <=17){
    statMod = +3
    return statMod;
  }
  else if (stat >= 18 && stat <=19){
    statMod = +4
    return statMod;
  }
  else if (stat >= 20 && stat <=21){
    statMod = +5;
    return statMod;
  }
  else if (stat >= 22 && stat <=23){
    statMod = +6;
    return statMod;
  }
  else if (stat >= 24 && stat <=25){
    statMod = +7;
    return statMod;
  }
  else if (stat >= 26 && stat <=27){
    statMod = +8;
    return statMod;
  }
  else if (stat >= 28 && stat <=29){
    statMod = +9;
    return statMod;
  }
  else if (stat === 30){
    statMod = +10;
    return statMod;
  }
  else{
    return "not caught";
  }
}


var assignStats = (x) => {
  var character = {};
  charater = x;
  if(character.class === "Barbarian")
  {
  var stats = dice.statList();
  stats.sort(function(a,b){return b - a});

  return character.str = stats[0];
  return character.con = stats[1];
  return character.dex = stats[2];
  return character.wis = stats[3];
  return character.cha = stats[4];
  return character.int = stats[5];
  }


}

module.exports = {
getRandSex,
calcBonus,
getRandSex,
getRandAlignment,
getRandClass,
assignStats,
getRandRace,
getRandName
}
```

I'm very new to this language so it's probable I'm overlooking something very basic, any assistance would be appreciated.

**SOLUTION**:

As advised by @Elmer Dantas, changing the format in which I exported my functions did the trick.

So, my original approach:

```
module.exports = {
getRandSex,
calcBonus,
getRandSex,
getRandAlignment,
getRandClass,
assignStats,
getRandRace,
getRandName
}
```

And the update and working approach:

```
exports.getRandSex = getRandSex;
exports.calcBonus = calcBonus;
exports.getRandAlignment = getRandAlignment;
exports.getRandClass = getRandClass;
exports.assignStats = assignStats;
exports.getRandClass = getRandClass;
exports.getRandRace = getRandRace;
exports.getRandName = getRandName;
```

Comment: i am not seeing that you required the utils.js file in app.js. As it is clear in error that it is unable to get the required function

Comment: @satyampathak I have updated my post, must have missed that in the copy/paste.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should change your export to be like this:

```
module.exports = {
    getRandSex: function(){},
    method2: function(){}
}
```

or even

```
exports.getRandSex = getRandSex;
//and so on
```

Comment: your second method worked! However I'm still not clear on the differences between your approach and my own, especially when my approach appeared to be working fine for a while.

Comment: Both my first example and your approach should work...I really don't get why you can't make it.

Answer (score 0):

Try 
import {getRandSex} from './util.js';
and use it in your file